# Entity Framework not saving all changes made to tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework, savechanges

I'm trying to save data to two different tables in one method. The first `db.SaveChanges()` call, updates the data correctly but the second time I call SaveChanges, it doesn't do anything, even when I clearly change the data.

```
PhaseStatus truckPhase = db.PhaseStatus.Where(x => x.TruckId == truckId).FirstOrDefault();
RTrucks truck = db.RTrucks.Where(x => x.Id == truckId).FirstOrDefault();

using (var ContextTransaction = db.Database.BeginTransaction())
{
    db.PhaseStatus.Attach(truckPhase);
    var entryPS = db.Entry(truckPhase);
    entryPS.State = EntityState.Modified;
    db.SaveChanges(); //Success

    if (truckPhase.Phase.PhaseName == "Not Started")
        truck.Status = "Quoted";
    else truck.Status = "Active";

    db.RTrucks.Attach(truck);
    var entryRT = db.Entry(truck);
    entryPS.State = EntityState.Modified;
    db.SaveChanges(); //Fails with no errors
    ContextTransaction.Commit();
}
```

Does anyone have any idea why EF6 would do this? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The second `db.SaveChanges()` goes through to `ContextTransaction.Commit()`, but there is no change of data in my RTrucks table...

Comment: Use this: db.RTrucks.Add(truck). Add() will do.

Comment: You are setting state of entryPS instead of entryRT. var entryRT = db.Entry(truck); entryPS.State = EntityState.Modified;

Comment: @AdilMammadov Great thx man! My problem 0)0

Comment: This happens when I just copy and paste and not look carefully when I get errors. People get easy points and I feel like an idiot...;P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your second block change:

```
entryPS.State = EntityState.Modified;
```

to

```
entryRT.State = EntityState.Modified;
```